# Unchecked unsafe operations

Tags: java

I am getting a warning about unchecked unsafe operations. I am not quite sure why I am getting this warning, but does anyone know what exception I should be trying to catch and where? I am assuming that I getting this warning because I am not checking for possible exceptions.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Tokenizer{

public static String split( String string )
{
    TreeSet tree = new TreeSet();
    StringTokenizer tokenizer =
    new StringTokenizer( string );

    while ( tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() )
    tree.add( tokenizer.nextToken() );

    String result = tree.toString();

    return result;
}//end of split

public static void main( String args[] )
{
    String str;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please input a string:");
    str = input.nextLine();
    split(str);

}//end of main
}//end of tokenizer
```

Comment: *"Not quite sure why I am getting this error"* ***What*** error? Quote the actual error message.

Comment: You need to indent your code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't using generics.

You should have something like:

```
Set<String> tree = new TreeSet<String> ();
```

Or add `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above your method (Not recommended)

Edit:
You can go here to get some more information on using generics:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java

Comment: But, this is a *warning*, while he indicates he has an *error*

Comment: If you take his code and compile it, you get: Tokenizer.java:16: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.TreeSet
tree.add( tokenizer.nextToken() );
        ^
1 warning

Comment: Which is a *warning*, not an *error*. Maybe the OP meant a warning though.

Comment: @amit: The warning is very nearly the title of the question, so the OP probably does mean this warning.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, not paying enough attention since it was only 1 line.

Comment: @Gren: It kinda mattered, what with `<String>` being invisible and all. ;-)

Comment: instead of adding with the while loop, I used a for loop and added them to the tree with the string.charAt() method. I was still getting the warning so I suppressed the warnings.